# Word.Document Contents -> Editing Text

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm currently have an issue trying to edit the Text inside my Document.Contents.Text

The following code does not work:

```
object findingFile = m_TempFileDirectory.FullName + "\\" + formField.Name + ".rtf";
Document tempDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref findingFile, ref m_Missing, 
  ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, 
  ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, 
  ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing);
tempDoc.Content.Select();
String st = tempDoc.Content.Text;
st = st.Replace("\r", "");
tempDoc.Content.Text = st;
tempDoc.Content.Copy();
tempDoc.Close(ref m_DiscardChanges, ref m_Missing, ref m_Missing);
r.Paste();
```

My outcome is still (I'm trying to remove the \r for New Line)

```
Lipid level: not specified\r
```

Comment: I updated my answer. If that doesn't help please explain what you're actually trying to do with the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I was wrong about escaping the \r, because of course you are replacing the actual control character (\r), not the literal "\r"'. Sorry.

You are correct in your comment, when you do `tempDoc.Content.Text = st;` a new linefeed (\r) gets appended. You will always need to remove or replace at the time that you actually use the value.

It looks like you want to copy the text to the clipboard? If so, why not just do it from the string (`st`):

```
        String st = tempDoc.Content.Text.Replace("\r", "\n");
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(st);
```

I also replaced the linefeeds with carriage-returns (\n), because if you don't do that there will be no linefeeds in the text at all (a problem if you have multiple lines of text).

(Original answer deleted)

Comment: You see, st is being replaced fine, but the moment I bring it back to tempDoc.Contents.Text (It isn't read only, or I'd get an error). It still adds the \r.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
st = st.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n\r", "");
```

**Side Note:**

`\n` Used as a new line character in Unix.

`\r` Used as a new line character in Mac.

`\n\r` Used as a new line character in Windows.

Comment: You see, st is being replaced fine, but the moment I bring it back to tempDoc.Contents.Text (It isn't read only, or I'd get an error). It still adds the \r.

Comment: did you checked properly? string is immutable in .Net. Hence if `st` is replaced with our intent, then there is no way for the Document to add the same on same location.